# DDS frequency synthesizer digital phase lock loop

Tags: frequency, fpga, phase

I am working on a project about a frequency-hopping tranceiver. I want to implement a phase lock loop on FPGA i.e. a digital PLL. I am multiplying the incoming signal with a certain frequency and passing it through a LPF. Now I give this low frequency to DDS. I want my DDS to work like a VCO and lock to incoming phase/frequency. How can I do that?

I also need to know that how the phase accumulator in a DDS works: how or what input they are getting to generate corresponding frequency?

Comment: You will have better luck with this question if you ask it at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, you might want to drop words like "plz" and clean up your capitalization a bit.  We are professionals here.

Comment: See also here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5710/all-digital-phase-lock-loop

Answer (score 0):

The [datasheets](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ipdsp_modulatdemodulat_ddscompiler.htm) of the Xilinx DDS Compiler have some information about the theory of operation. You may want to have a look at them.